# Finding the equation that is described by this block diagram

Tags: dynamical-systems, recurrence-relations

I have the following block diagram
[image]

The exercise asks to find the equation that describes the system.

**What I did:** I called what going into the $-1$ multiplier as $x_{1}$and
I got $2$ equations

$$y(k)=u(k-2)-x_{1}(k-2)+y(k-3)$$
$$x_{1}(k)=u(k-1)-x_{1}(k-1)+y(k-2)$$

How can I continue from here ? or maybe what I did is not a good way
to solve the question, what alternative way may be good here ?

Comment: After each block, name the signal, say $v_1$, $v_2$, etc... and then it should become clear.

Comment: @EdGorcenski - I denoted $x_2(k)$ as what comes out from the $+$ block, $x_4$ is for the one the comes out of the $-1$, $x_3$ is for what comes out from the lower Delay block.I wrote $4$ equations and got $x_2(k)=u(k)-x_2(k-1)+y(k-1)$. I just can't get rid out of the $x_i$ and have the relation between $y(k)$ and other $y$'s and $u$'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've labeled signals in your block diagram.

[image]

Let's just walk back up the chain. There's a good chance I made some mistakes in my subscripts and delays, since I tried solving this on a post-it note... please feel free to edit if there are :D

$$
\begin{align*}
y(k) &= v_3(k) \\
 &= v_2(k-1) \\
 &= v_1(k-2) \\
 &= v_4(k-2) + v_5(k-2) + u(k-2) \\
\end{align*}
$$

Now, let's figure out what $v_5(k)$ and $v_4(k)$ are.

$$
v_5(k) = v_3(k-1) = y(k-1)
$$
so
$$
v_5(k-2) = y(k-3).
$$

Next, for $v_4(k)$,
$$
\begin{align*}
v_4(k) &= -v_2(k) \\
 &= -v_1(k-1) \\
 &= v_4(k-1)-y(k-2)-u(k-1).
\end{align*}
$$
This means that
$$ v_4(k-2) = v_4(k-3)-y(k-4)-u(k-3). $$

Plugging this all in,

$$y(k) = u(k-2)+y(k-3)+v_4(k-3)-y(k-4)-u(k-3)$$

This makes sense, since we write our **observable state** in terms of previous state observations $y(k-3),y(k-4)$, **control input** $u(k-2), u(k-3)$, and a single direct state measurement $v_4(k-3)$.

Edit: now the signal names match the diagram.

Comment: Can't you just say $v_4(k)=y(k-1)$ and get rid of the internal state?  I think $v_5(k)$ should be $-y(k-1)$ so we get $y(k)=y(k-3)-y(k-1)+u(k-2)$

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake here in my labeling. My hand-drawn diagram switches $v_4$ and $v_5$. I should edit.

But yes, that is exactly what I did $v_5(k) = y(k-1)$. I am still not certain I can remove the internal state.

Comment: With the new labeling, $v_4(k-2)=-y(k-1),$ so $y(k)=-y(k-1)+y(k-3)+u(k-2)$, still the same.